# Why is this string declared this way in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I don't understand this declaration:

```
cifre DB N+1,?,N+1 DUP('$')
```

Where N is declared as `N EQU 10`.
DB contain a string of max 10 characters (read from keyboard). But, why `N+1,?,N+1 DUP('$')`?

Answer (score 0):

This definition essentially defines following byte structure:

`11, ? , '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'`

Why ?

`?` - Means the memory is not initialized
`DUP` - The number after DB defines how many bytes to repeat for, and then the `$` defines what to repeat.

`DB contain a string of max 10 characters`

This statement is incorrect. DB stands for define Byte which means it cannot hold more than 1 byte. What you might be saying that `cfire` points to a byte array which is 10 bytes in length.

Comment: Why `N + 1`? `int 21h/0Ah` counts the CR that ends input as one of the characters, so if you need 10 "useful characters", you need to format the buffer for 11.